# grep Not Displaying Results Due To Apparent Garbage Characters In File

Tags: bash

I have a file which I have removed all ^M from each line.  I can vi the file fine. Here are the first few lines I see in vi after issuing "vi filename":

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [isdb_testdb]    Script Date: 9/15/2023 2:43:35 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [isdb_testdb]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
```

If I do "more filename", I get a couple of unprintable characters at the top and then a screen full of nothing before the "--More--(0%)" message at the bottom.  There is obviously some invisible garbage that is causing issues.  A grep "CREATE DATABASE" filename returns no output and the exit code is 1.  The file looks and acts fine in vi.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Try `xxd filename`. It might be e.g. UTF-16.

Comment: *How* did you remove the ^M? The characters may be a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - which should be removed as well if you use `dos2unix`

Comment: Ty to use this procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129142/end-of-line-m-character-on-ubuntu